# What is the difference between "const int& jj" and "int& const jj"?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, language-lawyer

I am confused with the two. I am aware of the C++ references which are inherently constant and once set they cannot be changed to refer to something else.

Comment: Does your compiler accept the 2nd variant?

Comment: Please specify which compiler accepted the second variant for you.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi That's not a duplicate at all. That question deals with `const int &` and `int const &`, both valid (and equivalent) forms. This one deals with `const int &` and the syntax error `int & const`.

Comment: Yes GCC and Clang both did not accept the latter one.

Comment: @Angew: I did not notice that the "const" is after the "&". sorry I withdraw my close vote

Comment: @username_4567 That is something you should at least state in your question. As in, ask whether the latter one is actually even valid. This way, the question looks as if you did no research yourself before posting it.

Comment: @Angew I agree. My bad! I should have done some research but I never thought that this would be invalid because in pointers context having "const" after and before type specifier is valid so I thought even this is valid but may be redundant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`const int&` means reference to const `int`. (Similarly, `int&` means reference to non-const `int`.)

`int& const` literally means const reference (to non-const `int`), which is invalid in C++, because reference itself can't be const-qualified.

[$8.3.2/1 References [dcl.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#1)

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers
>   are introduced through the use of a typedef-name ([dcl.typedef],
>   [temp.param]) or decltype-specifier ([dcl.type.simple]), in which case
>   the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

As you said, references are inherently constant and once set they cannot be changed to refer to something else. (We can't rebind a reference after its initialization.) This implies reference is always "const", then const-qualified reference or const-unqualified reference might not make sense actually.

Answer (score 3):

`const` qualifier applied to reference means that you can't change the referenced value. For example:

```
void foo(int& arg) {
   arg = 1; // OK. The value passed by a caller will be changed in-place.
}

void foo(const int& arg) {
   arg = 1; // Compilation error.
}
```

`int& const jj` is a compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

Difference :

```
const int& jj// means a reference to const int.

int& const jj // ill formed code that should trigger a compiler error
```