# Would calling the default parameter with `new` cause memory leak?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks, default-parameters

I am trying to write a function that returns the center point of biggest detected object. No problem here. The issue is that I also want to return the foreground mask from parameters, if the user wants to use it.

In order to handle this situation, my solution is as following:

```
cv::Point detect(const cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat &mask = *new cv::Mat());
```

If `mask` parameter is specified, it can be used in `main`. Does RAII works in the other case, or would there be a memory leak?

**Note:** I know I can overload the function by 2 lines, but I want to know is it possible to do it properly by using default parameters, and not using pointers (input type is strict).

**Another note:** If `cv::noArray()` or a similar function can be used, that is totally okay.

Example usage:

```
char ch = 0;
while (ch != 27) // ESC is pressed
{
    cap >> img;
    if (img.empty())
        break;
    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::Point pt = detect(img, mask);
    // or pt = detect(img);
    cv::imshow("original", img);
    cv::imshow("foreground", mask);
    ch = cv::waitKey(1);
}
```

Comment: Impossible to say. The code could delete the underlying pointer, in which case there’s no leak. But that’s crufty. Don’t do it.

Comment: RAII is a design pattern that you have to implement, it's not something that C++ just enforces for free. I assume that if the user passes a value for `mask`, you don't delete the `cv::Mat` at the end of `detect`, which means you will indeed have a memory leak. Just take a pointer and use `cv::Mat* p_Mask = nullptr` or something if you want them to be able to call it without a mask.

Comment: a memory leak is not where you create something via new, but where you miss to delete it.

Comment: Since the argument is a reference, the code still have a reference to the object, and can use the address-of operator `&` to get a pointer to it for `delete`. However there's another problem with that default arguments, and it's that lvalue references can't bind to rvalues which is what the result of `*new cv::Mat()` would be.

Comment: @NathanPierson That is desired behaviour if `mask` is specified. I suppose there would be no problem in that case. Added an example code.

Comment: @user2864740 I want to make it easy for user. If I choose to use a pointer, either `imshow("foreground", *mask);`, or a pointer to reference is required.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `lvalue references can't bind to rvalues` that is what I get when I try to use `cv::Mat &mask = cv::Mat()`. If I remember correctly, VC++ does not complain, but Ubuntu GCC gives error.

Comment: `x = *new X` is almost never correct, don't do that.

Comment: @Burak VC++ have a non-standard and non-portable extension that allows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that introduces a memory leak. You might instead consider using a tuple return value:

```cpp
std::tuple<cv::Point, cv::Mat> detect(const cv::Mat &img);
```

or making `mask` a pointer:

```cpp
cv::Point detect(const cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat *mask = nullptr);
```

You could also try to keep the same signature with a cast. This is ugly but it might work:

```cpp
cv::Point detect(const cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat &mask = const_cast<cv::Mat&>(static_cast<cv::Mat const&>(cv::Mat())));
```

Comment: I am aware of the first two solutions. Can you explain what it does in the third?

Comment: `error: ‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘cv::Mat&’` [const reference to non-cost object is compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631317/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-jj-and-int-const-jj#answer-39631367)

Comment: I've replaced the C-style casts with `const_cast` and `static_cast`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439619/invalid-initialization-of-non-const-reference-from-an-rvalue for another example

Comment: With `const_cast`, now it works. This is what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but no memory leak:

```
cv::Point detect(const cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat &mask = *std::make_unique<cv::Mat>());
```

If the user does not provide a mask, one will be created. `detect` will write the mask back, which is then immediately destroyed. Using an overload will be more efficient as it can skip the needless update.

Alternatively, use `cv::Mat* mask = nullptr`. I don't know what you mean by "(input type is strict)." but for an experienced C++ programmer the `cv::Mat* mask = nullptr` pattern is clear: optional out parameter, no ownership transfer implied.

Comment: Well, it requires additional `memory` library and C++14. Most importantly, GCC version should be at least 5. `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.0)` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609271/errormake-unique-is-not-a-member-of-std) Those are very high prerequisites for such a simple function.

Comment: I don't use pointer because OpenCV `OutputArray` is used as like this. See [`Canny` Edge Detector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d5c/tutorial_canny_detector.html) for example.

Comment: @Burak: Well, we're at C++17/20 now, and GCC 10, so C++14/GCC 5 didn't seem unreasonable. Either way, you can just use the underlying `std::unique_ptr<cv::Mat>` from C++11, or going _way_ back, Boost and C++98 from the previous century.

Comment: The version of CMake installed by APT on Ubuntu 18.04 is currently 3.10.2.

Comment: It is interesting that `make_shared` requires C++11 whereas `make_unique` is C++14 standard. Shared is generally more applicable and I would expect the other way round.

Comment: @Burak: That's because `make_shared` was originally designed as an optimization. It usually co-locates the shared control block with the object itself, saving one allocation and reducing fragmentation. Since `unique_ptr` is a no-overhead pointer, there's no need for a similar optimization. `make_unique` was added for consistency and simplicity.